# Cannot install Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, packer, provisioning

So I am creating a packer template for docker with the image *php:7.0-apache*.
I added a shell provisioner where I try to install ansible so I can provision the image:

```
{
            "type": "shell",
            "inline": [
                "apt-get -y update",
                "apt-get install -y software-properties-common",
                "apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible",
                "apt-get -y update",

                "apt-get install -y sudo",
                "apt-get install -y ansible"
            ]
        },
```

However, I get this error. Why is that?
[image]

**EDIT**: After installing the gnupg package, there still seems to be issues that result in the building process to fail:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I managed to test your scenario manually against the `php:7.0-apache` docker image. Note that this image is based on `debian:stretch`. In your question, you are following the install guide for ubuntu which will fail anyway in debian stretch.

I'm using the correct scenario below. See the [ansible install documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-on-debian) for more details. I also kept the install of sudo which was in your initial provisioning script.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y gnupg sudo
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 93C4A3FD7BB9C367
echo deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu trusty main >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y ansible
apt-get clean
```

After playing this, result:

```
root@18ab6da8ac92:/var/www/html# ansible --version              
ansible 2.9.4
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22) [GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
```

Now, the above is installing ansible from deb packages that will run in python 2.7 that has been obsoleted. I much rather prefer the following scenario using pip that will install ansible as well but in python3 and does not need to add a supplementary apt repo neither requires to install gnupg

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python3-pip
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip install ansible
apt-get clean
```

And the result

```
root@e6b73a5f1d59:/var/www/html# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.4
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) [GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
```

Comment: Thanks. The second approach you suggested seems much cleaner. I'll go with that one.

Answer (score 3):

As it says, `No such file or directory: 'gpg'`, so you probably need to install `gnupg` before adding the PPA repository:

```
apt-get install gnupg
```

Comment: Unfortunately, after installing gnupg, the exact same error persists. Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Kyu96 You have to install `gnupg` before you use `apt-add-repository`

Comment: @Zeitounator @Hedi Nasr After installing the gnupg package correctly (before doing the `git-add-repository`) there still seem to be issues related to gpg? I am not sure what causes the build process to fail exactly..